# Why custom css class does not work on React-Semantic-UI elements?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I created card with react-semantic-ui, I want to add some extra styles via css class.

**One example is**:

I add custom 'card' class with box-shadow property, and that style is not applied.

```
          HTML PART:

import './App.css';


          {/* CLAIM CARDS SECTION */}

                  <Card className='card'>
                    <Card.Content>
                      <Card.Header style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center'}}>       
                        <h4>
                          Church Mutual Worker's Compensation Claim 
                          <span style={{marginLeft: '130px'}}>Claim #1234567</span>
                        </h4>
                      </Card.Header>
                    </Card.Content>
                  </Card>
```

CSS PART OF CODE: App.css

```
 .header-height {
      height: 12rem;
    }

    .header-title-color {
      color: black;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .card {
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px grey;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .red {
      color: red;
    }
```

Does someone have solution how to add custom css class to the React-semantic-ui components?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Give your className a bit more specific name, like claim_Card. After that in your css you need to override sematic's default css by adding your className to existing semantic's css for that component. In your case it would be something like

```
.ui.card.claim_Card {
  background: #455332; //for example
}
```

This will give your css rule more specificity and will override default semantic css. Anyway, check in your browser inspector what css class is applied to your element that you want to style and use that className (in this case .ui.card) and add on it your className definition and rules.

Comment: Hello Lazare, that is solution for my problem. 
Thank you again brate!

Answer (score 4):

Since `class` is a keyword in JavaScript, you should use `className` instead of `class` in React.

```
<Card className='card'>
```

Comment: Steel doesn't work. 
Here is screenshot: http://prntscr.com/kuqtr6
Thanks for rply.

Comment: It would have been helpful if you had provided your css code.

Comment: I updated post, added App.js(Html part)  App.css file.