# Remove white space in grid between images using Semantic UI and React

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui, fomantic-ui

I'm making an image gallery using Semantic UI and I'm having some difficulties getting rid of the extra white space between images that aren't as big as others. [Here's the link to the codesandbox repo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-varahamihira-pkfrz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) I know Semantic UI's grid is based off of flexbox but I'm not sure how I can modify it.[I want to make the grid come out like this](https://avada.theme-fusion.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/blog-grid-image.png)

If I have an array of images such as:

```
const images = { 
  {id: 1, source: '/image1.jpg' },
  { id: 2, source: '/image2.jpg' },
  { id: 3, source: '/image3.jpg' }
}
```

And map through it in a grid:

```
<Grid columns={3}>
    {images.map(image => (
      <Grid.Column key={image.key}>
        <Image src={image.source} />
      </Grid.Column>
    ))}
</Grid>
```

If I use this solution, there will be a lot of white space in between all of the images because of the different sizes.

Comment: I don't see the CodeSandbox link.

Comment: @AndyHoffman I just added the repo

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52345724/why-custom-css-class-does-not-work-on-react-semantic-ui-elements/52345893

Comment: @keikai No, I added a photo of what I want the grid to look like.

Answer (score 1):

So your current structure is mapping images like this:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

But the example you've shown is mapping images like this:

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

So instead of putting 1 image inside each Grid.Column component, you should put multiple images in each Grid.Column component. Theoretically 1/3 would be right in this case, but if you shrink the page width you might want to recalculate the number of columns.

```
let cols = this.state.numberOfColumns
let imagesplit = []
for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i + cols) {
  for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
    if (!imagesplit[j]) { imagesplit[j] = [] }
      if (images[i+j]) {
        imagesplit[j].push(images[i+j]
      }
  }
}
<Grid columns={cols}>
    { imagesplit.map(imagearray => {
      return imagearray.map(images => (
        <Grid.Column key={image.key}>
          <Image src={image.source} />
        </Grid.Column>
    ))}}}
</Grid>
```

Comment: I was thinking about that and how would I map over the array of images for multiple columns. I'm going to have multiple sets of images so I don't want to manually add all the images to different cloumns.

Comment: Okay, phew, example. Please excuse my formatting, I'm on a mobile but I tried!